# No interface method putArray in class WritableMap React-Native

Tags: react-native

I use RN version: "0.61.5"

The problem is that I installed [react-native-beacons-manager](https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager) 1.0.7 (note that the npm version the last time was updated a long time ago, but I tried the last Github version as well) but I can't use it as when I try to run my application the app crashes. Moreover, it doesn't show the red screen with an error stack trace. I looked into logs and found out that the problem is connected with WrittableArray, here's logs

```
2020-05-05 06:20:49.500 5218-5306/com.freeline E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[BeaconIntentProcessor]
    Process: com.freeline, PID: 5218
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method putArray(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/facebook/react/bridge/WritableArray;)V in class Lcom/facebook/react/bridge/WritableMap; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap' appears in /data/app/com.freeline-BgN5GbjFCm9weblBl35oBw==/base.apk)
        at com.mackentoch.beaconsandroid.BeaconsAndroidModule.createRangingResponse(BeaconsAndroidModule.java:299)
        at com.mackentoch.beaconsandroid.BeaconsAndroidModule.access$300(BeaconsAndroidModule.java:37)
        at com.mackentoch.beaconsandroid.BeaconsAndroidModule$2.didRangeBeaconsInRegion(BeaconsAndroidModule.java:280)
        at org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor.onHandleIntent(BeaconIntentProcessor.java:68)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:76)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

I found the function that caused the crashes, here it is:

```
    private WritableMap createRangingResponse(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        WritableMap map = new WritableNativeMap();
        map.putString("identifier", region.getUniqueId());
        map.putString("uuid", region.getId1() != null ? region.getId1().toString() : "");
        WritableArray a = new WritableNativeArray();
        for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
            WritableMap b = new WritableNativeMap();
            b.putString("uuid", beacon.getId1().toString());
            b.putInt("major", beacon.getId2().toInt());
            b.putInt("minor", beacon.getId3().toInt());
            b.putInt("rssi", beacon.getRssi());
            b.putDouble("distance", beacon.getDistance());
            b.putString("proximity", getProximity(beacon.getDistance()));
            a.pushMap(b);
        }
        map.putArray("beacons", a); // <- The line that produces the exception
        return map;
    }
```

Then I read a bunch of posts and understand that the problem is in the implementation of WritableMap in new versions of RN.

So, my question is: Is there any method to resolve it, I've already addressed the issue [here](https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager/issues/184#issuecomment-622659683). I'm aware of the possibility of downgrading the RN version to ^60, but I'd keep it as the last possible method.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem simply by downgrading to the version 60.6 of RN.